# Codeigniter or_where_in

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, where-clause

I am trying to combine these two queries in Codeigniter. So the row either has to have the user_id of $user eg 3 OR have an id matching the array $repost. I know how to do or_where but how do you do or_where_in?

Thanks

```
$this->db->where("user_id", "$user");
if (isset($conditions["repost"])) {

        $user_favourited = $conditions["repost"];

        $this->db->where("user_id", $user_favourited);
        $this->db->select("post_id");
        $this->db->from($this->repost_table);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        $id['posts'] = $query->result_array();

        foreach($id['posts'] as $post) {
            $repost[] = $post['post_id'];
        }

        if (isset($repost)) {
            $this->db->where_in('id', $repost);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->or_where_in();
```

**Syntax:**

```
or_where_in([$key = NULL[, $values = NULL[, $escape = NULL]]])
```

**Parameters:**

```
$key (string) – The field to search
$values (array) – The values searched on
$escape (bool) – Whether to escape values and identifiers
```

**Returns:**

```
DB_query_builder instance
```

**Return type:**

```
object
```

Generates a WHERE field IN(‘item’, ‘item’) SQL query, joined with ‘OR’ if appropriate.

More information here:  https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=or_where_in#CI_DB_query_builder::or_where_in