# CodeIgniter : how to write where_in OR where_in query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, where-in

I'm using codeigniter to query a database, and I need to conditionally compare arrays in the where clause.

So basically I want to do: where_in OR where_in depending on what array has data in it. So I will have either an array of user_id OR an array of area_id's.

I'm not sure how to combine the where_in comparison. This is the query i need to amends:

```
public function get_checks_test($org_id,$users,$areas) {
    // get todays date
    $todays_date = date("Y-m-d");
    // build where array
    $check_array = array('c.org_id =' => $org_id, 'c.status !=' => '0', 'c.due <=' => $todays_date);
    // build query
    $this->db->select('c.*,a.check_area_id,b.check_user_id,d.area_name,u.first_name,u.last_name');
    $this->db->order_by('c.due', 'asc');
    $this->db->where($check_array);
    $this->db->where_in('user_id', $users);
    $this->db->or_where_in('area_id', $areas);
    $this->db->join('check_assigned_areas a','a.check_id = c.check_id','left');
    $this->db->join('check_assigned_users b','b.check_id = c.check_id','left');
    $this->db->join('areas d','d.area_id = a.check_area_id','left');
    $this->db->join('users u','u.id = b.check_user_id','left');
    $check_object = $this->db->get('checks c');
    return $check_object->result();
}
```

I don't think there is a or_where_in function that I can find.

Can I do it like this or do I need a rethink?

Thanks

Comment: PLease check this one if it will help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21946311/codeigniter-or-where-in

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where_in#CI_DB_query_builder::or_where_in

Comment: "I don't think there is a or_where_in function that I can find." and  yet it's a function that is both in the documentation as @sintakonte pointed out as well as all over the web, including StackOverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a [or_where_in](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=or_where_in#CI_DB_query_builder::or_where_in) function in Codeigniter.

**Example**

```
$arr_price=array(20,40,80,30);
$this->db->or_where_in('price', $arr_price);
//SQL Query: OR price IN(20,40,80,30);
```

**Syntax:**

```
or_where_in([$key = NULL[, $values = NULL[, $escape = NULL]]])
```

**Parameters:**

```
$key (string) – The field to search
$values (array) – The values searched on
$escape (bool) – Whether to escape values and identifiers
```

**Returns:**

```
DB_query_builder instance
```

**Return type:**

```
object
```

Generates a WHERE field IN(‘item’, ‘item’) SQL query, joined with ‘OR’ if appropriate.
Generates a WHERE field IN(‘item’, ‘item’) SQL query, joined with ‘OR’ if appropriate.

If more help needed, I'm happy to help. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you want:

```
if(!empty($users)){
    $this->db->where_in('user_id', $users);
}
elseif(!empty($areas)){
    $this->db->where_in('area_id', $areas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using "left" join then in any case never use "where condition" as `or_where_in` and `where_in` because it will make array() for that left query if it not found.

```
$this->db->join('users u', 'u.id = b.check_user_id and u.id=' . $users, 'left');
```